# Python 3.8.10 Reading file ignores changes

Tags: python, file

Hi and thank you in advance!
I'm pulling my hair out with a weird issue I have concerning editing a txt file in python. I'm opening reading and edit a file and at some point when I try to write to it again the file is as it was before the edits! I'm no programmer just a scripting guy with lots to learn. Please have you any idea what is going on?
The ultimate goal is to detect a line and duplicate it... in this example line 18 of the text file must be duplicated before anything else..

```
    output = 'file1.txt'
        with open(output, 'r') as fr:
            for line in lines:          
                if ptr == 9:
                    heats.append(line[11:19].strip())
                if ptr == 10:
                    heats.append(line[11:19].strip())
                if ptr == 11:
                    heats.append(line[11:19].strip())
                if ptr == 12:
                    heats.append(line[11:19].strip())
                if ptr == 13:
                    heats.append(line[11:19].strip())
                if ptr == 16:
                    chem_heats.append(line)
                if ptr == 17:
                    chem_heats.append(line)
                if ptr == 18:
                    chem_heats.append(line)
                if ptr == 19:
                    chem_heats.append(line)             
                if ptr == 20:
                    chem_heats.append(line)
                ptr += 1
    #find duplicate heats--->         
    #    print(heats)
    #    print(chem_heats)
        seen = set()
        dupes = []
        ptr = 1 
        for x in heats:
           if x in seen:
               dupes.append(x)
           else:
               seen.add(x)
        duplicate=str(dupes)[2:7]
        duplicate_instances = len(dupes)
        for chem_line in chem_heats:
            if chem_line[:5] == duplicate:
                os.system("sed -i '/^"+duplicate+".*/a  "+chem_line+"' " + output)
        ptr = 1
    #find duplicate heats<---
        openFile = open(output, "r")
        readFile = openFile.read()
        print (readFile )
        with open(output, 'w') as fw:            
            for line in lines:
                if ptr == 7:
                    newldata = line[0:35]+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata           
                if ptr == 9:
                    newldata = line[20:48]+"\n"
                    heat_1 = line[11:19].strip()
                    weight_1 = line[52:60].rstrip()
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 10:
                    newldata = line[20:48]+"\n"
                    heat_2 = line[11:19].strip()
                    weight_2 = line[52:60].rstrip()
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 11:
                    newldata = line[20:48]+"\n"
                    heat_3 = line[11:19].strip()
                    weight_3 = line[52:60].rstrip()
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 12:
                    newldata = line[20:48]+"\n"
                    heat_4 = line[11:19].strip()
                    weight_4 = line[52:60].rstrip()
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 13:
                    newldata = line[20:48]+"\n"
                    heat_5 = line[11:19].strip()
                    weight_5 = line[52:60].rstrip()
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 14:
                    newldata = " ".join(line[47:].split())+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 15:
                    newldata = " ".join(line.split())+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 16:
                    newldata = " ".join(line.split())+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                if ptr == 17:
                    newldata = " ".join(line.split())+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata 
                if ptr == 18:
                    newldata = " ".join(line.split())+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata   
                if ptr == 19:
                    newldata = " ".join(line.split())+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata                   
                if ptr == 20:
                    newldata = " ".join(line.split())+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata 
                if ptr == 23:
                    newldata = " ".join(line.split())+"\n"
                    line_hardness_hdr = newldata.rstrip()
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata                   
                if ptr in range(25,35): #mechanical properties
                    newldata = line[4:45]+"\n"
                    lines[(ptr-1)] = newldata
                ptr += 1
            fw.writelines(lines)
        os.system("sed -i '35,$d' " + output)
        os.system("sed -i '/^[[:space:]]*$/d' " + output)
        os.system("sed -i '5,6d' " + output)
        os.system("sed -i '6d' " + output)
        os.system("sed -i '12d' " + output)
        os.system("sed -i '17,20d' " + output)
    #<-- Clean up ends
    #--> Generate variables
        with open(output, 'r') as fr:
        # reading line by line
            lines = fr.readlines()
        line_flds = 'Rp0.2;Rp1.0;Rm;A5;A50;A80;'
        reqs_l1= lines[0].rstrip()
        reqs_l2= lines[1].rstrip()
        reqs_l3= lines[2].rstrip()
        reqs_l4= lines[3].rstrip()
        grade = lines[4].rstrip()
        size_1 = (lines[5].replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        size_2 = (lines[6].replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        size_3 = (lines[7].replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        size_4 = (lines[8].replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        size_5 = (lines[9].replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        #sample data heat1
        sample1_1_rp02 = lines[16][6:10].rstrip()
        sample1_1_rp10 = lines[16][11:15].rstrip()
        sample1_1_rm = lines[16][16:20].rstrip()
        sample1_1_a5 = lines[16][21:25].rstrip()
        sample1_1_a50 = lines[16][26:30].rstrip()
        sample1_1_a80 = lines[16][31:35].rstrip()
        sample1_1_hardness = lines[16][36:40].rstrip()
        sample2_1_rp02 = lines[17][6:10].rstrip()
        sample2_1_rp10 = lines[17][11:15].rstrip()
        sample2_1_rm = lines[17][16:20].rstrip()
        sample2_1_a5 = lines[17][21:25].rstrip()
        sample2_1_a50 = lines[17][26:30].rstrip()
        sample2_1_a80 = lines[17][31:35].rstrip()
        sample2_1_hardness = lines[17][36:40].rstrip()
        sample1_1 = ((sample1_1_rp02+';'+sample1_1_rp10+';'+sample1_1_rm+';'+sample1_1_a5+';'+sample1_1_a50+';'+sample1_1_a80+';'+sample1_1_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        sample2_1 = ((sample2_1_rp02+';'+sample2_1_rp10+';'+sample2_1_rm+';'+sample2_1_a5+';'+sample2_1_a50+';'+sample2_1_a80+';'+sample2_1_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        chemical_comp_1 = (((lines[11][6:]).replace(" ",";")).rstrip())+";"
        c_fields_count_1 = chemical_comp_1.count(';')
        if c_fields_count_1 < 12:
            missing_f = 12 - c_fields_count_1    
        chemical_comp_1 = chemical_comp_1+(missing_f * ";")
        extra_c_fields_1 = (((lines[10]).replace(" ","%;")).rstrip())+"%;"
        extra_c_fields_count_1 = extra_c_fields_1.count(';')
        if extra_c_fields_count_1 < 5:
            extra_missing_fields_1 = 5 - extra_c_fields_count_1
        extra_c_fields_1 = extra_c_fields_1+(extra_missing_fields_1 * ";")
        row_1 = cert_num+";"+date+";"+marking+";"+reqs_l1+";"+reqs_l2+";"+reqs_l3+";"+reqs_l4+";"+grade+";"+size_1+";"+weight_1+";"+heat_1+";"+line_flds+line_hardness_hdr+";"+sample1_1+sample2_1+"C%;Si%;Mn%;P%;S%;Cr%;Ni%;"+extra_c_fields_1+chemical_comp_1
        #sample data heat1 end
        #sample data heat2
        sample1_2_rp02 = lines[18][6:10].rstrip()
        sample1_2_rp10 = lines[18][11:15].rstrip()
        sample1_2_rm = lines[18][16:20].rstrip()
        sample1_2_a5 = lines[18][21:25].rstrip()
        sample1_2_a50 = lines[18][26:30].rstrip()
        sample1_2_a80 = lines[18][31:35].rstrip()
        sample1_2_hardness = lines[18][36:40].rstrip()
        sample2_2_rp02 = lines[19][6:10].rstrip()
        sample2_2_rp10 = lines[19][11:15].rstrip()
        sample2_2_rm = lines[19][16:20].rstrip()
        sample2_2_a5 = lines[19][21:25].rstrip()
        sample2_2_a50 = lines[19][26:30].rstrip()
        sample2_2_a80 = lines[19][31:35].rstrip()
        sample2_2_hardness = lines[19][36:40].rstrip()
        sample1_2 = ((sample1_2_rp02+';'+sample1_2_rp10+';'+sample1_2_rm+';'+sample1_2_a5+';'+sample1_2_a50+';'+sample1_2_a80+';'+sample1_2_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        sample2_2 = ((sample2_2_rp02+';'+sample2_2_rp10+';'+sample2_2_rm+';'+sample2_2_a5+';'+sample2_2_a50+';'+sample2_2_a80+';'+sample2_2_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        chemical_comp_2 = (((lines[12][6:]).replace(" ",";")).rstrip())+";"
        c_fields_count_2 = chemical_comp_2.count(';')
        if c_fields_count_2 < 12:
            missing_f = 12 - c_fields_count_2    
        chemical_comp_2 = chemical_comp_2+(missing_f * ";")
        extra_c_fields_2 = (((lines[10]).replace(" ","%;")).rstrip())+"%;"
        extra_c_fields_count_2 = extra_c_fields_2.count(';')
        if extra_c_fields_count_2 < 5:
            extra_missing_fields_2 = 5 - extra_c_fields_count_2
        extra_c_fields_2 = extra_c_fields_2+(extra_missing_fields_2 * ";")
        row_2 = cert_num+";"+date+";"+marking+";"+reqs_l1+";"+reqs_l2+";"+reqs_l3+";"+reqs_l4+";"+grade+";"+size_2+";"+weight_2+";"+heat_2+";"+line_flds+line_hardness_hdr+";"+sample1_2+sample2_2+"C%;Si%;Mn%;P%;S%;Cr%;Ni%;"+extra_c_fields_2+chemical_comp_2
        #sample data heat2 end
        #sample data heat3
        sample1_3_rp02 = lines[20][6:10].rstrip()
        sample1_3_rp10 = lines[20][11:15].rstrip()
        sample1_3_rm = lines[20][16:20].rstrip()
        sample1_3_a5 = lines[20][21:25].rstrip()
        sample1_3_a50 = lines[20][26:30].rstrip()
        sample1_3_a80 = lines[20][31:35].rstrip()
        sample1_3_hardness = lines[20][36:40].rstrip()
        sample2_3_rp02 = lines[21][6:10].rstrip()
        sample2_3_rp10 = lines[21][11:15].rstrip()
        sample2_3_rm = lines[21][16:20].rstrip()
        sample2_3_a5 = lines[21][21:25].rstrip()
        sample2_3_a50 = lines[21][26:30].rstrip()
        sample2_3_a80 = lines[21][31:35].rstrip()
        sample2_3_hardness = lines[21][36:40].rstrip()
        sample1_3 = ((sample1_3_rp02+';'+sample1_3_rp10+';'+sample1_3_rm+';'+sample1_3_a5+';'+sample1_3_a50+';'+sample1_3_a80+';'+sample1_3_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        sample2_3 = ((sample2_3_rp02+';'+sample2_3_rp10+';'+sample2_3_rm+';'+sample2_3_a5+';'+sample2_3_a50+';'+sample2_3_a80+';'+sample2_3_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        chemical_comp_3 = (((lines[13][6:]).replace(" ",";")).rstrip())+";"
        c_fields_count_3 = chemical_comp_3.count(';')
        if c_fields_count_3 < 12:
            missing_f = 12 - c_fields_count_3    
        chemical_comp_3 = chemical_comp_3+(missing_f * ";")
        extra_c_fields_3 = (((lines[10]).replace(" ","%;")).rstrip())+"%;"
        extra_c_fields_count_3 = extra_c_fields_3.count(';')
        if extra_c_fields_count_3 < 5:
            extra_missing_fields_3 = 5 - extra_c_fields_count_3
        extra_c_fields_3 = extra_c_fields_3+(extra_missing_fields_3 * ";")
        row_3 = cert_num+";"+date+";"+marking+";"+reqs_l1+";"+reqs_l2+";"+reqs_l3+";"+reqs_l4+";"+grade+";"+size_3+";"+weight_3+";"+heat_3+";"+line_flds+line_hardness_hdr+";"+sample1_3+sample2_3+"C%;Si%;Mn%;P%;S%;Cr%;Ni%;"+extra_c_fields_3+chemical_comp_3
        #sample data heat3
        #sample data heat4
        sample1_4_rp02 = lines[22][6:10].rstrip()
        sample1_4_rp10 = lines[22][11:15].rstrip()
        sample1_4_rm = lines[22][16:20].rstrip()
        sample1_4_a5 = lines[22][21:25].rstrip()
        sample1_4_a50 = lines[22][26:30].rstrip()
        sample1_4_a80 = lines[22][31:35].rstrip()
        sample1_4_hardness = lines[22][36:40].rstrip()
        sample2_4_rp02 = lines[23][6:10].rstrip()
        sample2_4_rp10 = lines[23][11:15].rstrip()
        sample2_4_rm = lines[23][16:20].rstrip()
        sample2_4_a5 = lines[23][21:25].rstrip()
        sample2_4_a50 = lines[23][26:30].rstrip()
        sample2_4_a80 = lines[23][31:35].rstrip()
        sample2_4_hardness = lines[23][36:40].rstrip()
        sample1_4 = ((sample1_4_rp02+';'+sample1_4_rp10+';'+sample1_4_rm+';'+sample1_4_a5+';'+sample1_4_a50+';'+sample1_4_a80+';'+sample1_4_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        sample2_4 = ((sample2_4_rp02+';'+sample2_4_rp10+';'+sample2_4_rm+';'+sample2_4_a5+';'+sample2_4_a50+';'+sample2_4_a80+';'+sample2_4_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        chemical_comp_4 = (((lines[14][6:]).replace(" ",";")).rstrip())+";"
        c_fields_count_4 = chemical_comp_4.count(';')
        if c_fields_count_4 < 12:
            missing_f = 12 - c_fields_count_4    
        chemical_comp_4 = chemical_comp_4+(missing_f * ";")
        extra_c_fields_4 = (((lines[10]).replace(" ","%;")).rstrip())+"%;"
        extra_c_fields_count_4 = extra_c_fields_4.count(';')
        if extra_c_fields_count_4 < 5:
            extra_missing_fields_4 = 5 - extra_c_fields_count_4
        extra_c_fields_4 = extra_c_fields_4+(extra_missing_fields_4 * ";")
        row_4 = cert_num+";"+date+";"+marking+";"+reqs_l1+";"+reqs_l2+";"+reqs_l3+";"+reqs_l4+";"+grade+";"+size_4+";"+weight_4+";"+heat_4+";"+line_flds+line_hardness_hdr+";"+sample1_4+sample2_4+"C%;Si%;Mn%;P%;S%;Cr%;Ni%;"+extra_c_fields_4+chemical_comp_4
        #sample data heat4 end
        #sample data heat5
        sample1_5_rp02 = lines[24][6:10].rstrip()
        sample1_5_rp10 = lines[24][11:15].rstrip()
        sample1_5_rm = lines[24][16:20].rstrip()
        sample1_5_a5 = lines[24][21:25].rstrip()
        sample1_5_a50 = lines[24][26:30].rstrip()
        sample1_5_a80 = lines[24][31:35].rstrip()
        sample1_5_hardness = lines[24][36:40].rstrip()
        sample2_5_rp02 = lines[25][6:10].rstrip()
        sample2_5_rp10 = lines[25][11:15].rstrip()
        sample2_5_rm = lines[25][16:20].rstrip()
        sample2_5_a5 = lines[25][21:25].rstrip()
        sample2_5_a50 = lines[25][26:30].rstrip()
        sample2_5_a80 = lines[25][31:35].rstrip()
        sample2_5_hardness = lines[25][36:40].rstrip()
        sample1_5 = ((sample1_5_rp02+';'+sample1_5_rp10+';'+sample1_5_rm+';'+sample1_5_a5+';'+sample1_5_a50+';'+sample1_5_a80+';'+sample1_5_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        sample2_5 = ((sample2_5_rp02+';'+sample2_5_rp10+';'+sample2_5_rm+';'+sample2_5_a5+';'+sample2_5_a50+';'+sample2_5_a80+';'+sample2_5_hardness+';').replace(" ", "")).rstrip()
        chemical_comp_5 = (((lines[15][6:]).replace(" ",";")).rstrip())+";"
        c_fields_count_5 = chemical_comp_5.count(';')
        if c_fields_count_5 < 12:
            missing_f = 12 - c_fields_count_5    
        chemical_comp_5 = chemical_comp_5+(missing_f * ";")
        extra_c_fields_5 = (((lines[10]).replace(" ","%;")).rstrip())+"%;"
        extra_c_fields_count_5 = extra_c_fields_5.count(';')
        if extra_c_fields_count_5 < 5:
            extra_missing_fields_5 = 5 - extra_c_fields_count_5
        extra_c_fields_5 = extra_c_fields_5+(extra_missing_fields_5 * ";")
        row_5 = cert_num+";"+date+";"+marking+";"+reqs_l1+";"+reqs_l2+";"+reqs_l3+";"+reqs_l4+";"+grade+";"+size_5+";"+weight_5+";"+heat_5+";"+line_flds+line_hardness_hdr+";"+sample1_5+sample2_5+"C%;Si%;Mn%;P%;S%;Cr%;Ni%;"+extra_c_fields_5+chemical_comp_5
        #sample data heat5 end
        export = open('out.csv', 'w')
        export.write(row_1+'\n'+row_2+'\n'+row_3+'\n'+row_4+'\n'+row_5)
        export.flush()
```

And this is the txt file to process:

```
EN 10088-4:2009
AD 2000 W2, W10 & EN 10028-7:2016
ASTM A240/A240M
ASME SA-240/SA-240M II A ED. 2021
                                                                 AOD
COIL
1.4301 TYPE 304                        EN ISO 9445-2
1.4301 2B
  1      1 33564 3  0,6 X 1250 MM                   14070 KG  2B
  2      2 38026 1  0,6 X 1250 MM                   11850 KG  2B
  3      3 35800 2  0,7 X 1500 MM                   11710 KG  2B
  4      4 35800 2  0,7 X 1500 MM                   11380 KG  2B
  5      5 38426 5  0,8 X 1250 MM                   13580 KG  2B
                                               N
                                               %
33564 0,04  0,43 1,34 0,033 0,002 18,2  8,6    0,042
38026 0,04  0,51 1,46 0,032 <.001 18,2  8,6    0,043
35800 0,036 0,48 1,45 0,035 0,001 18,2  8,7    0,045
38426 0,04  0,41 1,12 0,030 <.001 18,2  9,0    0,068
                               A50 A80                 
                                                       
                                         HBW           
                                                       
  1  01   266  294  638        63   59   144           
     02   260  289  635        62   58   143           
  2  11   276  297  632        60   57   141           
     12   263  287  624        61   58   143           
  3  01   256  288  614        61   58   132           
     02   284  324  625        58   55   149           
  4  01   256  288  614        61   58   132           
     02   284  324  625        58   55   149           
  5  01   255  287  605        62   59   148           
     02   251  284  608        64   60   145           
                                     OK
                                     OK
                                     OK
```

Up until the code below the file is edited just fine, after that it reverts as before adding the line in the code before it....

```
    #find duplicate heats<---
        openFile = open(output, "r")
        readFile = openFile.read()
        print (readFile )
```

Comment: See how to create a [mcve] and edit the question. Most of what you have posted is completely irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: >> The ultimate goal is to detect a line and duplicate it... 
To simplify, maybe start with a dummy file with just 1-2 lines of text and see if you can use part(s) of your code to duplicate that line and write it back, and what problems you face

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.